# Como criar links em html que sejam direcionados a pontos específicos da própria página?

Tags: html, link, notepad++

Ultimamente notei que algumas páginas em `html` mesmo estando offline tinham links que direcionavam o usuário a pontos específicos da própria página e gostaria de aprender a fazer isto no `Notepad++`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Tenta assim:

```
<a href="#ponto1">Link</a>
```

O `#ponto1` é um `id` de um elemento da página logo quando o link for clicado você será redirecionado ao ponto onde tem o `id`.

Deste modo:

```
<div id="ponto0"><a href="#ponto1">Link</a>palavras palavras palavras palavras palavras <br>palavras palavras palavras palavras palavras palavras palavras palavras <br>palavras palavras palavras palavras palavras palavras palavras palavras <br>palavras palavras </div>
<div id="ponto1">Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto <br>Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto </div>
```

Quando clicar `href` será redirecionada até a segunda `div` que possui um `id` que casa com o link da tag `<a>` *Não esqueça que deve iniciar com `#`